# jQuery: selecting a parent attribute from a callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

given this html code:

```
<td><img class='del' id='4' src='images/delete.gif'></td>
```

I am in trouble understanding how to complete the following code:

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){ 
        setup();                            
    }
);

function setup(){
    $("#deleteForm").hide();
    $("img.del").bind('click', formDisplay);
}   

function formDisplay(){
   $("#deleteForm").show();
}
```

Here I need to pass to the callback the value of the `id` attribute of the image element but I have some problem to understand how `this` or `$('this')` work in jQuery

Still better, I would like to have html code this way:

```
<tr id='4'>
   <td>...</td><td>...</td><td><img class='del' src='images/delete.gif'></td>
</tr>
```

being able to get the value of each of the child of the `<tr>` element identified by its id from *within* the callback.

Has someone some advices?

Many thanks

Comment: some of your code doesn't show up. edit?

Comment: Sorry, at start I was horribly dumb. Forgot to quote code :-(

Comment: Well ... this site is unbelievable. I had just the type my question to get proper answers... Good grief.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just re-formatting bendewey's answer:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("#deleteForm").hide(); 
    $("img.del").click(function() { 
        $("#deleteForm").show();
        $(this).attr('id');  // this is the image Id
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready( function(){ 
    setup(); 
});

function setup() { 
    $("#deleteForm").hide(); 
    $("img.del").bind('click', formDisplay); 
} 

function formDisplay() { 
    $("#deleteForm").show();
    $(this).attr('id');  // this is the image Id
    $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');  // this is the tr Id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's small example. This method works for any parent tags.

If you click all three buttons one by one output should be (please note that console.log() is Firebug function, you can replace it with alert if dont have Firebug installed):

- td
- div
- body

Please note the last result. TD without table is not considered as parent in this case.

Here's the code:

```
<body class="body">

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        setup();
    });

    function setup() {
        $("#deleteForm").hide();
        $("img.del").click(formDisplay);
    }

    function formDisplay() {
        $("#deleteForm").show();
        var p = $(this).parent(); // parent tag
        p.attr('id');  // this is the image id -- what you need
        console.log(p.attr("class")); // show parent element class to show difference
    }

</script>

<table class="table">
<tr class="tr">
<td class="td"><img class='del' id='4' src='images/delete.gif'></td>
</tr>
</table>

<div class="div"><img class='del' id='5' src='images/delete.gif'></div>

<td class="td"><img class='del' id='6' src='images/delete.gif'></td>

<div id="deleteForm">text</div>

</body>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this (method structure removed for clarity):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("deleteForm").hide();

    $("img.del").click(function(){
        $("#deleteForm").show();
        $(this).id; // I can't remember if this is cross-platform or not, but you get the idea...
    }
});
```

Comment: I totally combine your two answers into 1 :D

Comment: (btw I hadn't seen them before I posted, etc etc)

Comment: I don't think $(this).id will work.  the not wrapped version would work for sure this.id.

Comment: Yeah true, I'm being dumb. Apparently my post was edited as well, although I can't quite see where. Or why.